# How to randomly shuffle values in a map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl, shuffle

I have a std::map with both key and value as integers. Now I want to randomly shuffle the map, so keys point to a different value at random. I tried random_shuffle but it doesn't compile. Note that I am not trying to shuffle the keys, which makes no sense for a map. I'm trying to randomise the values.

I could push the values into a vector, shuffle that and then copy back. Is there a better way?

Comment: If the keys are more compact than your values, you can push the keys into a vector, shuffle that, then use those to determine your new value sequence.

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can push all the keys in a `vector`, shuffle the `vector` and use it to swap the values in the `map`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}
int main ()
{
    srand(time(0));
    map<int,string> m;
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        m.insert(pair<int,string>(i,("v"+to_string(i))));

    for(auto i: m)
    {
        cout << i.first << ":" << i.second << endl;
        v.push_back(i.first);
    }
    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(),myrandom);
    vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();
    cout << endl;
    for(auto& i:m)
    {
        string ts=i.second;
        i.second=m[*it];
        m[*it]=ts;
        it++;
    }
    for(auto i: m)
    {
        cout << i.first << ":" << i.second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of your proposal is `O(N)`, (both the copies and the shuffle have linear complexity) which seems optimal (looking at less elements would introduce non-randomness into your shuffle).

If you want to repeatedly shuffle  your data, you could maintain a map of type `<Key, size_t>` (i.e. the proverbial level of indirection) that indexes into a `std::vector<Value>` and then just shuffle that vector repeatedly. That saves you all the copying in exchange for `O(N)` space overhead. If the `Value` type itself is expensive, you have an extra `vector<size_t>` of indices into the real data on which you do the shuffling.

For convenience sake, you could encapsulate the `map` and `vector` inside one class that exposes a `shuffle()` member function. Such a wrapper would also need to expose the basic lookup / insertion / erase functionality of the underyling map.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @tmyklebu in the comments, maintaining (raw or smart) pointers to secondary data can be subject to **iterator invalidation** (e.g. when inserting new elements at the end that causes the vector's capacity to be resized). Using indices instead of pointers solves the "insertion at the end" problem. But when writing the wrapper class you need to make sure that insertions of new key-value pairs never cause "insertions in the middle" for your secondary data because that would also invalidate the indices. A more robust library solution would be to use [**Boost.MultiIndex**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), which is specifically designed to allow multiple types of view over a data structure.

Comment: The raw pointers *are* bad, actually, because adding an element to the vector can invalidate those pointers.

Comment: @tmyklebu agreed (and your point also holds for smart pointers or any other kind of iterator btw), a better way would be to let the map store indices to the vector of data, which would not be subject to iterator invalidation

Answer (score 0):

Well, with only using the map i think of that:
make a flag array for each cell of the map, randomly generate two integers s.t. 0<=i, j < size of map; swap them and mark these cells as swapped. iterate for all.
EDIT: the array is allocate by the size of the map, and is a local array.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it...

But... Why not write a quick class that has 2 vectors in. A sorted `std::vector` of keys and a `std::random_shuffle`d `std::vector` of values? Lookup the key using `std::lower_bound` and use `std::distance` and `std::advance` to get the value. Easy!

Without thinking too deeply, this should have similar complexity to `std::map` and possibly better locality of reference.

Some untested and unfinished code to get you started.

```
template <class Key, class T>
class random_map
{
public:
    T& at(Key const& key);
    void shuffle();
private:
    std::vector<Key> d_keys; // Hold the keys of the *map*; MUST be sorted.
    std::vector<T> d_values;
}

template <class Key, class T>
T& random_map<Key, T>::at(Key const& key)
{
    auto lb = std::lower_bound(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end(), key);
    if(key < *lb) {
        throw std::out_of_range();
    }
    auto delta = std::difference(d_keys.begin(), lb);
    auto it = std::advance(d_values.begin(), lb);
    return *it;
}

template <class Key, class T>
void random_map<Key, T>::shuffle()
{
    random_shuffle(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end());
}
```

Comment: @neil-kirk What do you think?

Comment: Somehow you should enforce the class invariant that the `vector<Key>` is sorted (to keep `O(log N)` lookups) but keeping `O(log N)` insertion seems quite hard this way.

Comment: @rhalbersma Strictly speaking you can't keep it using plain old vectors, but... I would guess in many low use cases, it will be quicker than `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle the map in place, you can implement your own version of `random_shuffle` for your `map`. The solution still requires placing the keys into a vector, which is done below using `transform`:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> map_type;
map_type m;
m[10] = "hello";
m[20] = "world";
m[30] = "!";
std::vector<map_type::key_type> v(m.size());
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), v.begin(),
               [](const map_type::value_type &x){
                   return x.first;
               });
srand48(time(0));
auto n = m.size();
for (auto i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
    map_type::size_type r = drand48() * (i+1);
    std::swap(m[v[i]], m[v[r]]);
}
```

I used `drand48()/srand48()` for a uniform pseudo random number generator, but you can use whatever is best for you.

Alternatively, you can shuffle `v`, and then rebuild the `map`, such as:

```
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
map_type m2 = m;
int i = 0;
for (auto &x : m) {
    x.second = m2[v[i++]];
}
```

But, I wanted to illustrate that implementing shuffle on the map in place isn't overly burdensome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using `std::reference_wrapper` of C++11.

First, let's make a version of std::random_shuffle that shuffles references. It is a small modification of *version 1* from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle): using the `get` method to get to the referenced values.

```
template< class RandomIt >
void shuffleRefs( RandomIt first, RandomIt last ) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type i, n;
    n = last - first;
    for (i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first[i].get(), first[std::rand() % (i+1)].get());
    }
}
```

Now it's easy:

```
template <class MapType>
void shuffleMap(MapType &map) {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<typename MapType::mapped_type>> v;
    for (auto &el : map) v.push_back(std::ref(el.second));
    shuffleRefs(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```