# Create new map from random subset of map in C++

Tags: c++

I have a map `std::map<unsigned int,double> areas` from which I would like to draw a random subset of random size (uniform distribution). So far I know how to pick a single random element.

```
const int range_from  = 1;
const int range_to    = areas.size();
std::random_device                  rand_dev;
std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(range_from, range_to);
std::map<unsigned int,double>::iterator rand_element;
auto itrtr = ++areas.begin();
std::advance(itrtr, distr(generator));
unsigned int random_key = itrtr->first;
rand_element = areas.find(random_key);
```

How would I extend this algorithm? Or would a different ansatz be better?

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650991/pick-a-unique-random-subset-from-a-set-of-unique-values ?

Comment: @m.s. using a random permutation is a really elegant solution

Comment: Is the target size truly random, or do you have an exact number of samples to take?

Comment: [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) - Yes, it is. But it's of course good to know how to specify the size of the subset. So far, I could only find e.g. the [insert method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080489/copy-subset-of-a-stdmap). But I wonder whether there is also a method where I'd only need to specify the length but not the position of the subset. But as the map is randomized beforehand, I can simply use the insert method and subset the map from its beginning to an arbitrary (<size ) or chosen end.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678093/m-s)'s comment and the answer by [Johnny Mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203529/johnny-mnemonic) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068927/how-to-randomly-shuffle-values-in-a-map), I could come up with this solution:

```
std::map<unsigned int,double> areas;
areas = computeAreas(); //fill areas map
areas[0] = 0;
std::vector<unsigned int> v;
// copy map keys to vector
  for(auto it = ++areas.begin(); 
    it != areas.end(); ++it) {
    v.push_back(it->first);
  }
// randomize vector elements
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
auto it=v.begin();

  for(auto& i:areas){
    double values=i.second;
    i.second=areas[*it];
    areas[*it]=values;
    it++;
  }
```

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated and will soon be removed. Some more `auto`s would help a great deal, too.

Comment: [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin) - thanks, I corrected the code. Concerning an alternative to `std::random_shuffle` there's still some time for me to find one, I hope. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get a random sampling you can iterate through the entire map, using random numbers to determine which elements will be kept and which will be discarded. There are two ways of calculating the odds for keeping vs. discarding, depending on whether you need an exact count or not.

For a random count, using e.g. taking 1 out of 10 samples on average:

```
int sample_rate = 10;
std::random_device                  rand_dev;
std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(0, sample_rate - 1);
std::map<unsigned int,double> result;
for (auto it = areas.begin(); it != areas.end(); ++it)
{
    if (distr(generator) == 0)
        result.insert(*it);
}
```

For an exact count, taking e.g. 1/10 of the input:

```
int result_size = areas.size() / 10;
int countdown = areas.size() - 1;
std::random_device                  rand_dev;
std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
std::map<unsigned int,double> result;
for (auto it = areas.begin(); it != areas.end(); ++it, --countdown)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, countdown);
    if (distr(generator) < result_size - result.size())
        result.insert(*it);
}
```

Comment: Thanks [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom), your code taught me a bit. This would work only for a reasonably large `areas.size()`. In my case, it changes over time, i.e. from 1e0 to 1e3. Thus, I assume I'd either follow another ansatz or include a compensatory term on the right hand side of `result_size`.

Comment: @fitzy_blarb of course you can use any formula you'd like to calculate `result_size`, or pass it into a function from somewhere else. The code works even if `result_size` is greater than your original data set, returning the entire data set in that case.